# GCD of binomial coefficients of the form ($p^n$ choose $k$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, gcd-and-lcm

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $p$ be a prime.  Find the greatest common factor of $\binom{p^n}{1}, \binom{p^n}{2},...,\binom{p^n}{p^n-1}$.

---

*Progress*: We know that for any given $n$ and $k$ in $\binom{p^n}{k}$, $$ \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \biggl \lfloor \dfrac{p^n}{p^m} \biggr \rfloor \geq \sum_{m=1}^\infty \biggl [\biggl \lfloor \dfrac{p^n-k}{p^m} \biggr \rfloor + \biggl \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^m} \biggr \rfloor \biggr]$$ because of the inequality $\displaystyle \lfloor x+y \rfloor \geq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor$. But this doesn't prove that each combination has to be divisible by $p^n$ because some may have no factors of $p$. So I am stuck here.

Comment: What do you think about it?

Comment: We know that for any given $n$ and $k$ in $\binom{p^n}{k}$, $\displaystyle \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \biggl \lfloor \dfrac{p^n}{p^m} \biggr \rfloor \geq \sum_{m=1}^\infty \biggl [\biggl \lfloor \dfrac{p^n-k}{p^m} \biggr \rfloor + \biggl \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^m} \biggr \rfloor \biggr]$ because of the inequality $\displaystyle \lfloor x+y \rfloor \geq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor$. But this doesn't prove that each combination has to be divisible by $p^n$ because some may have no factors of $p$. So I am stuck here.

Comment: When faced with a problem like this, especially if you get stuck, you should always always *always* compute a bunch of examples.  In this case, write down a chunk of Pascal's triangle until you run out of room and look at the rows that correspond to prime powers, like $4$, $8$, and $9$, and see if anything stands out.

Comment: It seems like the answer is $p^n$, but I am not sure how to prove it. Edit: Oh, wait. For $p^n = 9$ it doesn't hold.

Comment: @user1196158, if you do what I suggested in my previous comment, you should quickly convince yourself that the answer is **not** $p^n$.

Comment: Have you considered the case of $n=2,p=2$? In that case it is the GCD of 4 and 6 which is 2 and not 4 thus it isn't $p^n$ as a few of the smaller example cases would demonstrate, $9$ would be another if you need it.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. So I have a conjecture then. If $n = 1$, then the $gcd$ is $p^n$. Otherwise, it is $p$. In other words, I claim that the $gcd$ is always $p$.

Comment: @user1196158, excellent, now you're getting somewhere!  You might note that $p^1=p$, so you really don't need to split your conjecture into two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider 
$$
\binom{p^n}{p^{n-1}} = \frac{p^n(p^n-1) \cdots (p^n-p^{n-1}+1)}{p^{n-1} (p^{n-1}-1) \cdots 2 \cdot 1} = \prod_{i=0}^{p^{n-1}-1} \frac{p^n-i}{p^{n-1}-i}.
$$
For each $i > 0$, the denominator and numerator of the rightmost fraction contain the same amount of prime factors $p$ (namely the same amount as $i$ has). It follows that $\binom{p^n}{p^{n-1}}$ contains only one prime factor $p$. Since $\binom{p^n}{1} = p^n$, this means that the GCD is either $1$ or $p$. Can you exclude the first possibility?

Comment: Why can't the GCD be $1$?

Comment: You could try to count prime factors $p$ in a general term $\binom{p^n}{i}$, similar to what I did above.

Comment: Don't you mean that the numerator contains $1$ more factor of $p$ than the denominator?

Comment: Yes (because it contains one more when $i=0$).

Comment: We get  $\displaystyle \prod_{m=0}^{i-1} \frac{p^n-m}{i-m}$ for $\displaystyle \binom{p^n}{i}$. Then what?